# How do I download my public key (key pair) in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently changed the region of my EC2 instance via creating an AMI of the previous instance and sending it to the new region and launching a new instance from it. However, it now uses the key in the key pair in the old region.

In order to avoid confusion for myself in the future, I want to move the key from the key pair in the old region to the new region (so I have everything in the same region)

I can import the key into the new region, but to do so I need the public key. Question is, I have no idea how to get the public key. I've Googled and looked everywhere, can't find how to get the public half of my key on file so I can import it in the new region

How do I get the public key file?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Think it would be better to just make a new key for the region

Comment: Can I assign it to my instance?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#retrieving-the-public-key

Comment: Found the answer. Ty anyway

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#retrieving-the-public-key-windows

> On your local Windows computer, you can use PuTTYgen to get the public key for your key pair.
>
> Start PuTTYgen, choose Load, and select the .ppk or .pem file. PuTTYgen displays the public key.

Thank you, anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you can login to the ec2 instance, you should be able to go to your `~/.ssh` folder. You should see something like this:
[image]

You need to know the name of your public key. In my case, this is `id_rsa.pub`. Now you can open a terminal on your local computer and use `scp` command to copy the file into your local.

`l$ scp -i ~/.ssh/your_key.pem your_user_name@11.12.123.34:/home/your_user_name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/Desktop
id_rsa.pub                                                                            100%  405    16.5KB/s   00:00`

Now you should have the public key on your Desktop. Now you can go the new EC2, login into it (using password) and copy and paste the text in the `id_rsa.pub` into any file you want.